# Hilbert function of $k[x_1, x_2, x_3]/ (x_1^2,x_2^2x_3,x_2^3)$

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra

> If $R = k[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ is a polynomial ring and $I = (x_1^2,x_2^2x_3,x_2^3)$ how do you see that the Hilbert function $H(R/I,i) = 4$ for $i \geq 4$?

So the free resolution of $R/I$ is

$$0 \to R(-6) \to R(-4) \oplus R(-5)^2 \to R(-2) \oplus R(-3)^2 \to R \to R/I \to 0.$$

Now I know that $$H(R(-i),i) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & t < i\\ 
 \binom{n-1+t-i}{t - i}& t \geq i
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So, for example in $R(-6)$, I should get $\binom{2+t-6}{t-6}$. My problem is how to deal with the direct sums in the other complexes?

Comment: It seems you missed that the Hilbert function is additive on exact sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a free resolution in order to find the Hilbert function of this monomial ideal?

If you look at $k[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_1^2,x_2^2x_3,x_2^3)$ can immediately notice that the surviving monomials of degree $\ge4$ are: $\{x_3^4,x_2x_3^3, x_1x_3^3,x_1x_2x_3^2\},\{x_3^5,x_2x_3^4,x_1x_3^4,x_1x_2x_3^3\}$, and so on.

However, if you insist to use a resolution for finding $H(R/I,i)$, then notice that $$H(R/I,i)=H(R,i)-H(R,i-2)-2H(R,i-3)+H(R,i-4)+2H(R,i-5)-H(R,i-6)=\binom{i+2}{i}-\binom{i}{i-2}-2\binom{i-1}{i-3}+\binom{i-2}{i-4}+2\binom{i-3}{i-5}-\binom{i-4}{i-6}=4$$ for $i\ge4$.